# Call async function in other function

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I am having a problem with asynchronous functions. I have the following function which works fine and basically searches into the firebase realtime database for a matching username:

```
  static async getSnapshot(fc: FormControl){
    let isPresent:boolean = false;
    await firebase.database().ref().child("users").orderByChild("username")
    .equalTo(fc.value)
    .once("value", snapshot => {          
    }).then((data)=> {
      if(data.exists())
        isPresent = true;
      else
        isPresent = false;
    });
    console.log(isPresent);
    return isPresent; 
  }
```

The problem is when I call this function in another where I want to do other operations based on the result:

```
  static async validUsername(fc: FormControl){
    try{
      let bool:boolean =await this.getSnapshot(fc.value)
      if(bool===true)
         return  ({validUsername: true});         
      else{
         return (null); 
       } 
      }catch(e){
        console.log(e)
      }         
  }
```

The line :

```
let bool:boolean =await this.getSnapshot(fc.value)
```

returns the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSnapshot' of undefined
```

How can I modify my function? Thanks in advance for response

Comment: Could you please also add the code where you make the actual call of `validUsername`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` refers to an instance usually. Static methods don't belong to any instance so `this` doesn't make sense in them.

To fix your case, just use your class name instead of `this`. E.g.

```
   class APIHandlers {
      static async getSnapshot {...}

      static async validUsername(fc: FormControl){
          try{
            let bool:boolean = await APIHandlers.getSnapshot(fc.value);
          ...
       } 
   }
```

Comment: is this code tested? Funny thing in the playground this seems to work just fine: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/ATDGBsEMGduAVAptALpATpYBvAUCVSFAS1GBgE8A7Mgc0RQGUrIAHaACwHsUAKAM1AAuclQoBKPCBCQA7pGIowXKtC7hEAOnBdavAEQAjRMSq1giAB5WArikQATADTBB+8QG5809AxvoqV0hwaEQvEABfXG8CNBIyShpgADdg4gcAVVCAyABbRAFhUQkpaRR0ClLpYA0lQy51IXr1REhAgF5yeUVgFA5iaE16JhZ2bj5BTVTwG0RxGOlifl5m8Hb18tn56p3fFH9A4F5safSsxBz8kU3ECM8d6oWQRBDEKoe9g6OqG3Bwe6ekWAgIioCIoA4vDm72qoBUag02l0UO2D2AnwCwB+f3COwiaJA3nxhKiuDhqiU9lQwE6VEQsgQyDQmF4nlwSEImCmaUy2RY+QMhig7g8QA . I am curious about your ts.config

Comment: @EiriniGraonidou the error OP mentioned appears if we use an arrow function https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/ATDGBsEMGduAVAptALpATpYBvAUCVSFAS1GBgE8A7Mgc0RQGUrIAHaACwHsUAKAM1AAuclQoBKPCBCQA7pGIowXKtC7hEAOnBdavAEQAjRMSq1giAB5WArikQATADTBB+8QG5809AxvoqV0hwaEQvEABfXG8CNBIyADdg4gcAVVCAyABbRGAAXnJoalABYVEJfIA+KWkUdAoa6WANJUMudSE29URIQIK5BSUUDmJoTXomFnZuPkFNJPAbRHEY6WJ+Xi7wPJ26pZWmw98Uf0DgXmwFlPTETJyRPcQIz0Om1ZBEEMRG1+PT86oNnA4Be70iwDBEVARFAHF4yx+TVAKjUGm0unhB1ewD+AWAgOB4UOEWxIG8JLJUVwyNUQ2QSgKVEQsgQ9IwkF4nlwSEImHmyTSGRYOQMhig7g8QA

Comment: Then, it would make perfect sense. But it appears that the OP uses no arrow functions. Anyhow, it makes sense to refer to static methods using the class and not the instance. But would rather see this as a warning.